# Split list into two dependent on condition and return value from larger list

Tags: python, list

I have a list as following:

```
 mylist = [0.254, 0.754, 0.152, 0.981, 0.614]
```

My list contains numbers that are less than or equal to `0.5` and numbers greater than `0.5`.

I want to choose the most frequent category determined by how many are <= 0.5 versus how many are > 0.5.

For example, in the above list, since there are more numbers greater than 0.5 than less than 0.5, 3 versus 2, I want to return *one* of these numbers as the output, for example 0.754.

Comment: 0.254 and 0.152 is contain <0.5

Comment: And 0.754 isn't. It's not clear to me at all what you are asking.

Comment: You have no repeated values in your list, what are you asking?

Comment: @jackvern, I've tried to clarify your question. If this isn't what you want, please edit it so it is clear.

Comment: "I want to choose the most frequent list in my list" is surely a typo. You don't have a nested list. Please re-read your question and clarify. We don't have the privilege of knowing your actual problem, so we can only try to piece it together from what you actually write

Comment: I want the system to first compute the number of values greater than 0.5 and less than 0.5, and if, for example, values greater than 0.5 were more in the list, at the output of one of these numbers

Answer (score 2):

You can `filter` out two lists from the original and then return the most frequent of the larger list

```
l1 = list(filter(lambda x: x > .5, l))
l2 = list(filter(lambda x: x < .5, l))
if len(l1) > len(l2):
    print(max(set(l1), key = l1.count))
else:
    print(max(set(l2), key = l2.count))
```

> ```
> 0.754
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just go over the list, and append to the desired list. 
Keeping it simple as possible:

```
mylist = [0.254,0.754,0.152,0.981,0.614]

above = []
below = []
for num in mylist:
    if num > 0.5:
        above.append(num)
    else:
        below.append(num)
if len(above) > len(below):
    print(above[0])
elif len(below) != 0:
    print(below[0])
```

output:

```
0.754
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
random_value = None
my_list = [0.254,0.754,0.152,0.981,0.614]
small_list = [elem for elem in my_list if elem < 0.5]
large_list = [elem for elem in my_list if elem > 0.5]
try:
    if len(small_list) == len(large_list):
        random_value = random.choice(small_list)
    if len(small_list) < len(large_list):
        random_value = random.choice(small_list)
    else:
        random_value = random.choice(large_last)
    print(random_value)
except IndexError as e:
    print("something went wrong got two empty lists")
```

Comment: This seems to fit your requirement:

Comment: I want the system to first compute the number of values greater than 0.5 and less than 0.5, and if, for example, values greater than 0.5 were more in the list, at the output of one of these numbers

Comment: thnks,but i have a proble,if i get empty list in small_list orlarge_list i have a error:IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence

Comment: I just extended my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this problem by first determining the most common category; for example via `collections.Counter`. Then feed this into a generator comprehension and extract the first in-scope value.

The algorithm will have linear time complexity.

```
from collections import Counter

L = [0.254, 0.754, 0.152, 0.981, 0.614]
flag = Counter(i > 0.5 for i in L).most_common(1)[0]

L_filtered = (i for i in L if ((i > 0.5) if flag else (i <= 0.5)))
sample = next(iter(L_filtered))  # 0.754
```